# Fastest way to build a basic Flash app

Tags: flash

I need to write a really basic Flash app for my website in order to leverage XMLSocket() functionality.

What's the easiest way to compile some basic flash source without having to download a lot of bloatware?

Comment: I am sorry I know nothing about your question, but I am curious as to why you downvoted your own question...

Comment: You can't vote on your own questions/posts.  Otherwise, everyone would have infinite reputation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the Flex Framework at Abobe and install [FlashDevelop](http://flashdevelop.org). You might have to set up some paths... other than that you're good to go. FlashDevelop is pretty handy as an IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You will need either Flex or Adobe Flash. Flex is free and open source.